# Getting variables and calling functions with UI. Maya python

Tags: python, function, user-interface, variables, maya

I am currently working on a little script that creates a crane-like rig automatically in Autodesk Maya, the user gets to choose the amount of joints by a UI.

My question is how do I take the integer input of the user and use it as the variable value for my "jointAmount"?

I am also wondering how I would be able to call my function(AutoCraneRig) to actually run the script from the UI. I have a "apply"-button but I am unsure how to connect it to my function.

I have seen similar posts like mine but I feel that the solutions shown are somewhat hard for me to understand and/or I can't really relate what is shown to my own problem.

If anything is unclear or more information is needed from me please don't hesitate to call me out.

[Here is what my current UI look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PoAY.png)

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm


def jntctrl():
number = pm.intField(jnt, q=1, v=1)
print(number)

if pm.window("stuff", exists = True):
pm.deleteUI("stuff")

pm.window("stuff", t = "Crane Rig Generator", w=400, h=200)
pm.columnLayout(adj = True)

pm.text(label="Joint Amount:")
jnt = pm.intField(changeCommand = 'jntctrl()')

pm.button(label="Create Crane")

pm.showWindow()


#Defining how many joints the user want to have for their crane rig
jointAmmount = 5

#Defining how many controllers the user want to have to orient the crane. 
#May not exceed the joint amount
controllerAmount = 5

def autoCraneRig():
#Creating the joints
for i in range(jointAmmount):
  pm.joint()
  pm.move(0, i, 0)

#Creating the controllers
for i in range(controllerAmount):
    pm.circle()
    pm.rotate (0,90,0)
    pm.makeIdentity (apply= True)

#Creating the groups    
for i in range(controllerAmount):
    pm.group()

#Somehow one of the nurbs get parented to a group when running the script, here i select both the groups and then unparent them.
pm.select("group*", "nurbsCircle*")
pm.parent(world = True)

#Creating lists/dictionaries for the groups
#Since I wanted to parent my objects by their number I had to put all objects in lists/dictionries to get access.
groups = pm.ls('group*')
nbs = [int(n.split('group')[-1]) for n in groups]
groupDic = dict(zip(nbs, groups))

#Create a list/dictionary for the joints
joint = pm.ls('joint*', type='joint')
nbs = [int(n.split('joint')[-1]) for n in joint]
jointDic = dict(zip(nbs, joint))

common = list(set(groupDic.keys())&set(jointDic.keys()))

#Parenting the groups to the joints
for i in common:
    pm.parent(groupDic[i], jointDic[i])

#Reseting the transformations of the groups and then unparenting them to still have the transformation data of the joints    
pm.select("group*")
pm.makeIdentity()
pm.parent(world = True)

#Creating a list/dictionary for the nurbs aswell that will be parented to the groups in numeric order
nurbs_sh = pm.ls('nurbsCircle*', type='nurbsCurve')

#I had to get the transformation information from the nurbs before parenting them with anything would work(took a long time to get it right).
nurbs_tr = pm.listRelatives(nurbs_sh, p=1)
nbs = [int(n.split('nurbsCircle')[-1]) for n in nurbs_tr]
curveDic = dict(zip(nbs, nurbs_tr))

common = list(set(groupDic.keys())&set(curveDic.keys()))

#Parent the nurbs to the groups
for i in common:
    pm.parent(curveDic[i], groupDic[i])

#Select the nurbs and reset transformations and then freeze transform
pm.select("nurbsCircle*")
pm.makeIdentity()

#Orient constrain the controllers/nurbs to the joints
for i in common:
    pm.orientConstraint(curveDic[i], jointDic[i])

#Parent the 2nd group with the first controller. Do this for the whole hierarchy. 
for i in common:
    pm.parent(groupDic[i+1], curveDic[i])

#I'm getting keyError after I put the "+1" in my groupDic and I don't know why, although it still works, I guess.

autoCraneRig()
```

Comment: You can query the intfield value when you make a function for the "apply button"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how does one do that in this instance?

Comment: In jointctrl(), instead of print, do a return. In another function for your button Create Crane, do user_value = jointctrl()

Comment: Thank you!
I can now use the intfield value in my script.

Comment: But now I am having a different problem:
How do I make so that my function doesn't run until I press my "create Crane" button?

Comment: You have to use the `command` parameter in your `button` that points to your function. Check the example at the end of the docs, it's quite clear: http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/button.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example for how to call a specific function/command when a button is clicked, and how to get the value of an int field. The key is in naming the fields, so you can reference the UI control later.

```
import pymel.core as pm


def ui():
    if (pm.window("myWindow", exists=True)):
        pm.deleteUI("myWindow")

    window = pm.window("myWindow", t="My Window", w=400, h=200)
    pm.columnLayout(adj=True)
    pm.intField("myIntField")
    pm.button("Button", aop=True, command="action()")

    pm.showWindow(window)


def action():
    print("Button clicked!")
    value = pm.intField("myIntField", q=True, v=True)
    print(value)


ui()
```

If you want to get more into making UI's, I would recommend you watch these two videos:

- [PySide UI Creation in Maya: Video One](https://vimeo.com/122424605)
- [PySide UI Creation in Maya: Video Two](https://vimeo.com/123737031)